# How to hide the gallery folder in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, gallery, photo

I'm developing an android application to hide the photos gallery using a password to do it, and show it by using password also.

I searched online for such like this idea, but I didn't find yet and answer.
I would appreciate your help.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean system Gallery app or your application is going to be some kind of photos gallery?

Comment: I mean system Gallery app.

Comment: In this case it's possible only with root privileges + xposed framework (or analogs).

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your answer, I appreciate it.